# Sqlite delete all connected rows from 3 join table

Tags: sqlite, join, conditional-statements, inner-join, rows

How do you delete all rows connected from 2 different table in SQLite?

```
**Table1**         **Table2**                     **Table3**         
| ID | Number |    | ID | Tax | Table1ID |    | ID | Price | Table2ID |
| 1  |   0    |    | 1  | 21  |     1    |    | 1  |   56  |    1     |
| 2  |   1    |    | 2  | 15  |     2    |    | 2  |   5   |    2     |
| 3  |   0    |    | 3  | 10  |     3    |    | 3  |   98  |    3     |
```

I want to delete all rows from Table1-3 where Table1.Number = 0, how I can get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to define the tables properly so that `Table2.Table1ID` references `Table1.ID` and `Table3.Table2ID` references `Table2.ID` with the action `ON DELETE CASCADE`:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;

CREATE TABLE Table1(
    `ID` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    `Number` INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE Table2(
  `ID` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  `Tax` INTEGER,
  `Table1ID` INTEGER REFERENCES Table1(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE Table3(
  `ID` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  `Price` INTEGER,
  `Table2ID` INTEGER REFERENCES Table2(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Note that you must turn on the foreign key support because it is off by default.

Now every time you delete a row from Table1, all rows of Table2 that hold a reference to the deleted row of Table1 will be deleted too. 
Also all rows of Table3 that hold a reference to the deleted rows of Table2 will be deleted.

So all you need is:

```
DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE Number = 0;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=2650ff797b3e638c21a74ee3166bdfa8).